# Could not retrieve table list. - SQL Server Import and Export - SQL Server Native Client RDA 11.0

Tags: sql-server, sql-import-wizard, sql-server-native-client

I am trying to import data to database from text file. I have SQL Server 2019 installed. I am using SQL Server Native Client RDA 11.0. For some reason I cannot connect to the database when I want to set the data destination. This is the message I get:

> Could not retrieve table list. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>
> Client unable to establish connection
>
> Registry information is corrupt or missing. Make sure the provider is installed and registered correctly. (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0)
>
> Program Location:
>
> w System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
> w System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
> w System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> w System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) w System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> w System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
> w System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
> w Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.SQLServerForm.LoadDatabasesList()

I've tried looking for some solutions on the internet, but I haven't found anything concrete and I have no idea what to do about it next.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. After installing SQL Server 2012 Native Client, I was able to connect to the server.